# ignore digits after '.' regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I currently have this function for formatting numbers (adding commas every 3 digits):

```
formatNumber: (num) => {
        return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
},
```

The problem is that if the number has more than 3 decimal places, it also adds commas into the decimals. i would like to ignore everything after the `.`, but still return the number including the decimals. (ignore anything after the decimal, but still return that.)

For example, if I have `1000000.12341234` I would like it to return `1,000,000.12341234`

(the current function would return `1,000,000.12,341,234`)

Comment: A simple non-regex way would be split as the decimal, apply regex to first half and concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string contains only a single dot, you can assert after matching the digits using a positive lookahead `(?=\d*\.\d)` that there should be a dot followed by a digit at the right.

Note that you can replace with the full match `$&` instead of using groups.

```
\d(?=\d*\.\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A6eY0T/1)

```js
const s = "1000000.12341234";
const regex = /\d(?=\d*\.\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
console.log(s.replace(regex, "$&,"))
```